# Check if a List/ArrayList contains chars of a string Java

Tags: java, string, character

I want to check if a string is found in a given list filled with letters.
For example , if i have :

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
list.add("a");
list.add("e");
list.add("i");
list.add("o");
list.add("u");

String str = "aeo";

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (list.get(i).equals(str.charAt(j)))
            count++;
    }
System.out.println(count);
```

str is found in my letter list so I have to see my count having value 3 , because i've found 3 matches with the string in my list.
Anyway, count is printed with value 0 .
The main idea is that i have to check if str is found in the list no matter the order of the letters in str.

Comment: Why do you have `List<String>` and not `List<Character>`? And wouldn't it be _much_ easier to iterate over the `str` String to get its individual chars and then use `list.contains(strChar);`?

Comment: You're right :) . It's a lot easier to use chars to compare chars instead of strings.

Answer (score 5):

You are comparing a `String` to a `Character`, so `equals` returns `false`.

Compare `char`s instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
    for (int j=0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (list.get(i).charAt(0) == str.charAt(j)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

This is assuming your `list` contains only single character `String`s. BTW, if that's the case, you would replace it with a `char[]` :

```
char[] list = {'a','e','i','o','u'};
for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
        if (list[i] == str.charAt(j)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A string is not equals a character, so you have to convert the character to a string.

```
if (list.get(i).equals(String.valueOf(str.charAt(j))))
```

or the string to a char and compare it like that:

```
if (list.get(i).getCharAt(0)==str.charAt(j))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `streams` to get the answer in one line as shown below with inline comments:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();
//add elements to list

String str = "aeo";//input string

//split str input string with delimiter "" & convert to stream
long count = Arrays.stream(str.split("")).//splt the string to array
    filter(s -> list.contains(s)).//filter out which one matches from list
    count();//count how many matches found
System.out.println(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the character to the string:

```
list.get(i).equals(String.valueOf(str.charAt(j)))
```

The correct syntax to convert character to the string is:

```
list.get(i).charAt(0) == str.charAt(j)
```

`list.get(i).getCharAt(0)==str.charAt(j)` won't work as written in Jens' answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is right. Thanks for it . And I've also just checked now and saw that I could make my list :

```
ArrayList<Character> list ;
```

instead of

```
ArrayList<String> list ;
```